Confusion understanding the TREE(n) function in math
I am trying to learn about the tree(n) function in math.
Here is a video I was watching:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdvysiICfY8
Suppose I have red (R) and blue (B) nodes.
Tree(1) :

Option1 :  R

Tree(2) :

Option1:R
Option2: B-B
Option3: B

Here are my questions.

Isn't Option(1) Tree(1) contained in Option(2) Tree(2)? Is this not a contradiction?
In Tree(2), why is there no B-R tree?


Welcome, by the way, to Math SE. It is expected here that questions be fully and clearly stated so we know how to answer. A link to a video can be helpful, but it isn’t a substitute for expressing the question itself directly in one’s post. I invite you to edit your question accordingly.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Hmmm, I take back my comment about terminology. Per Wikipedia, there is a TREE function that is the object of some study and referred to by that name (at least by some). But that is exactly the kind of information that would be included as background and disambiguation in a well prepared question.
